Generators of Lie Algebra
The following comes from M. Maggiore, "A Modern Introduction to Quantum Field Theory".  The author introduces a representation $D_R(g)$ of a group element $g=g(\theta)$ depending on the set of parameters $\theta^a$. They then suppose $\theta^a$ is infinitesimal, and perform the following series expansion:
$$
D_R(\theta)\sim 1+i\theta_a T_R^a;\qquad
T_R^a\equiv -i\frac{\partial D_R}{\partial\theta^a}\vert_{\theta=0}
\tag{$\ast$}
$$
I don't understand the notation $D_R(\theta)$. Why wouldn't the author expand $D_R(g(\theta))$ like this:
$$
g(\theta) \sim g(0) + \theta_a\,\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta^a}\vert_{\theta=0}
\equiv e + \omega^a\theta_a
$$
where $e$ is the identity element, then consider
$$
D_R(g(\theta))
=D_R(e+\omega^a\theta_a)
\sim D_R(e) + i\omega_a T_R^a
=1+i\omega_a T_R^a
$$
This is almost the same as $(\ast)$, but with $\omega$ in lieu of $\theta$. Is just this a notational issue, or am I missing something?

You're almost correct. Certainly $D_R(\theta)$ is really shorthand for $D_R(g(\theta))$. However in your notation, $\omega_a$ is a matrix if $G$ a matrix group (or more generally $\omega_a$ is an element of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$). Then
$$
D_R(g(\theta)) \simeq D_R(e + \omega^a\theta_a) \simeq D_R(e) + T_eD_R(\omega^a)\theta_a = I + i\theta_a T_R^a,
$$
where $T_eD_R:\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})\simeq M_n(\mathbb{C})$ denotes the derivative of $D_R:G\to \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ at the identity, and $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the set of $n\times n$ complex matrices. In other words, using your notation
$$
T_R^a = -i\,T_eD_R(\omega^a) \in M_n(\mathbb{C}).
$$
Note that by definition of the derivative $T_eD_R$
$$
T_eD_R(\omega^a) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta^a}\Bigg\vert_{\theta=0}D_R(g(\theta))
$$
so this is consistent with Maggiore's definition.

Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

You're welcome!
